# Android: Draw Rectangle Over Another Rectangle on Canvas

Tags: java, android, android-canvas

I'm trying to draw one rectangle that's light gray over another rectangle that's white on a canvas, but it doesn't seem to do anything.  Here's what I've got:

```
public void onDraw(Canvas c) {
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.LTGRAY);
    c.drawRect(0, 0, width, height, paint);
    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    c.drawRect(10, 10, width - 10, height - 10, paint); //This is slightly smaller than the gray rectangle, so it looks kinda like a border.
}
```

To display this, I use setContentView() in the main activity to set the view to a new class extending SurfaceView.  When the surface is created in the custom SurfaceView, it starts a thread that executes onDraw() every 100 milliseconds.  I got the Canvas by using holder.lockCanvas(), then onDraw()ing and holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c).

Answer (score 0):

Where are you initializing your `width` and `height`? Are they set to 0?
Try calling `canvas.getWidth()` or `canvas.getHeight()`.

Comment: Just tried that, still no luck.  Thanks though, @user3339429 .

Comment: If you still have problems, show me how you are displaying the surface view! Maybe the surface view isn't getting any actual space on the screen, so height may be 0.. and your thread that is calling invalidate (or actually postinvalidate) might not be calling it properly.. If you need a way to call onDraw every set interval, use a handler with postDelayed instead of a thread if it is a long persisting animation/redraw

Comment: Updated the original post with what I've got.